# Spacing in HTML textbox

Tags: javascript, php, html

How do I remove this spacing from the textbox. PS: I've checked and confident that my variable does not contain any spacing to begin with.

[image: Refer to this picture]

At firstpage.php, I changed the php variable '$pcodevar' to javascript variable 'pcode' and pass it to upload.php.

```
function upload() {
var pcode=" <?php echo $pcodevar;?>";
var uploadwindow = window.open("upload.php", "_blank", "toolbar=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,top=500,left=500,width=400,height=400");
uploadwindow.pcode= pcode;}
```

At upload.php, i wrote a script to receive the variable and identify it as fid_17.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function initInput()
{
document.forms[0].fid_17.value = pcode;
}
</script>
```

Next still at upload.php,

```
<body onLoad="initInput()">
<form name="form1" method="post" action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data"/>
Project ID:
    <input name="fid_17" id="fid_17" value=""/><br><br>
Upload File: 
    <input type="text" name="t" placeholder="File name" />
    <input class="button blue" type="submit" name="upload" value="Upload/View!"/><br>
    <input type="file" name="f" /><br>
</form>
```

Thank you for helping!

Comment: Perhaps you need `=pcode.trim()` ? or `document.forms[0].fid_17.value = opener && opener.pcode?opener.pcode.trim():"";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should just trim the 'pcode' value before setting value.
Try to use `trim` function in php and js.
Also remove the leading space when setting $pcodevar(see below)

```
var pcode = "<?php echo trim($pcodevar);?>";
pcode = pcode.trim();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using .trim() on the "pcode". Please see, http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_trim_string.asp

If you don't need to support older browsers (i.e. IE8), please avoid using regular expression way

Answer (score 0):

You should use trim in PHP and JavaScript sides.

```
function upload() {
var pcode="<?php echo trim($pcodevar);?>";
pcode = pcode.trim();
var uploadwindow = window.open("upload.php", "_blank", "toolbar=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,top=500,left=500,width=400,height=400");
uploadwindow.pcode= pcode;}
```

Answer (score 0):

trim out the value you assigned to fid_17:-

```
document.getElementById('fid_17').value= pcode.trim()
```

also console out the value of pcode. hope this will help